# JVCL TJvThreadTimer.OnTimer : Is This Code Executed in The TJvThreadTimer, ie. NOT the main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer

I want to have the code executed by the OnTimer event to be executed in a separate (non-Main) background thread. this code does not access or communicate with the main thread/GUI. Simple question, I get the timer (TJvThreadTimer) is executed in it's own background thread, but:

Does the code contained in TJvThreadTimer.OnTimer event get executed in that background thread as well?

It is unclear from the limited documentation.

Thanks......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [timer's source code](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/jvcl/run/JvThreadTimer.pas) for yourself, you will see that the `OnTimer` event handler is called inside of a class method that is `Synchronize()`'ed by the internal background thread, which means the event handler runs in the main UI thread.

Comment: Thank you Remy. I have now also performed some tests which show the MainThread is indeed the Thread that the OnTimer code runs in. Your answer confirms my limited testing. Thanks for the response.