# Is there already a Delphi timer that executes its event in a separate thread from the Main?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timing

With reference to [JVCL TJvThreadTimer.OnTimer : Is This Code Executed in The TJvThreadTimer, ie. NOT the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111004), we know the JVCL threaded timer does its timing part in a thread, but the OnTimer code is executed in the main thread. At least, that's what I understood from that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Is there a timer component at hand that does both timing and event in a thread? Under 10msec resolution would be good too. My searching has not found one. Thank you.

Comment: Create a thread, and put a timer in it. Obviously not a GUI timer if you want high resolution. Put a high resolution timer in your thread.

Comment: If you are going to create your own thread, then look at [Waitable Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects). Otherwise, look at [Multimedia Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers). If you want to stick with JVCL's `TJvThreadTimer`, it would be trivial to remove the use of `Synchronize()` from its `OnTimer` event